# Analyzing Twitter data using R

Tags: r, twitter, rjson

I am trying to analyze Twitter data using R, by plotting the number of tweets over a period of time, when I write

```
plot(tweet_df$created_at, tweet_df$text)
```

I got this error message:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Here is the code which I used:

```
library("rjson")
json_file <- "tweet.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(file=json_file)
library("streamR")
tweet_df <- parseTweets(tweets=file)
#using the twitter data frame
tweet_df$created_at
tweet_df$text
plot(tweet_df$created_at, tweet_df$text)
```

Comment: R is confused because one or both of the variables you're passing to `plot` are not numeric. Rather than `tweet_df$text` I assume you need the number of tweets corresponding to each `created_at`.

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I want

Comment: Could you please provide `str(tweet_df)` and `head(tweet_df)`? Otherwise we can't know what the correct variable is to plot. (Perhaps just a relevant subset of the columns if they're hugely wide data frames.)

Comment: @Hana can you store your tweet.json file as a gist: https://gist.github.com/ so that we can access it and help you with your question?

Comment: it's $user_created_at, and $text

Comment: @jed here is a snippet of the data: [link](https://gist.github.com/Hana2020/a06b752da38489424279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple issues here, but nothing insurmountable. If you want to track tweets over time, you're really asking for the tweets created per x time frame (tweets per minute, second, whatever). So that means you only need the `created_at` column, and you can build the graph with R's `hist` function.

If you want to split by words mentioned in text or whatever, that's doable too but you should probably use `ggplot2` to do it and maybe ask a different question. Anyways it looks like `parseTweets` converts twitters timestamps to a character field, so you'll want to turn it into a `POSIXct` timestamp field that R can understand. Assuming you have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
❥ head(tweet_df[,c("id_str","created_at")])
              id_str                     created_at
1 597862782101561346 Mon May 11 20:36:09 +0000 2015
2 597862782097346560 Mon May 11 20:36:09 +0000 2015
3 597862782105694208 Mon May 11 20:36:09 +0000 2015
4 597862782105694210 Mon May 11 20:36:09 +0000 2015
5 597862782076198912 Mon May 11 20:36:09 +0000 2015
6 597862782114078720 Mon May 11 20:36:09 +0000 2015
```

You can do that like this:

```
❥ dated_tweets <- as.POSIXct(tweet_df$created_at, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
```

That will give you a vector of dated tweets in R's timestamp format. You can then plot them like this. I left open the sample twitter feed for 15 mins or so. This is the result:

```
❥ hist(dated_tweets, breaks ="secs", freq = TRUE)
```

[image]